# FBX exporter with a material overwrite with python

Tags: python, materials, scripting, .fbx

I am using the bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx operator and it works perfectly, but I was wondering if I am able to use the material overwrite for the export?

Comment: What do you mean by "material overwrite"?

Comment: in the properties panel under scene/overwrite/material overwrite

Comment: I thought you meant an options for fbx export. No, that won't work it's for rendering in Blender only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a work around. The key was saving the original material, assigning the overwrite material, then reapplying the original. You will need to change the settings for the fbx export click [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html?highlight=export%20scene#module-bpy.ops.export_scene) for its structure.

```
 fbxs = [ ob for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects]
 bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    for ob in fbxs:
         ob.select_set(True)
         mat = bpy.data.materials['Overwrite']
         original_mat = ob.data.materials
         ob.data.materials[0] = mat

         bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(...)

         ob.data.materials[0] = original_mat
         bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```